# वर्ष • (varṣ) according to ramayana

Tags: ramayana, astronomy

In Ramayana the sanskrit word that is used to describe 'year' is 'वर्ष (varṣ)'. Is that equal to 'year' as we describe today (one revolution of earth around sun)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because Hinduism follows lunar calendar. "one revolution of earth around sun" is Solar Calendar (counting days). Lunar Calendar is different from solar. One of the difference is that it has lesser days compared to solar calendar (in a year).

For more information you may search Lunar Calendar.

Is this what you are looking for?